# IE9 CSS graphic glitch (blue to dark background)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have this very strange bug on IE9:

[image: IE9 glitch]

On the latest version of Chrome, it looks like this:

[image: Normal behavior]

The star is added using an `::after` tag with a `content` property that uses a special font. I thought this could be the source of the glitch but even when using `content: "A";`, or removing it completely the glitch is still present.

What could be the cause of this?

**EDIT:** here are the CSS properties along with the HTML:

```
<button class="btn mark-score-4 star score_4 btn-large  markchoice " data-question-id="10112" value="4">
  <span></span>
  ::after  
</button>
```

CSS: http://pastebin.com/FL7Wd9yc

Span CSS: http://pastebin.com/XBQ4epie

::after CSS: http://pastebin.com/h0Rc1ni5

Comment: Where is the blue background coming from? It would help if you included a bit more code, thanks

Comment: That's the thing thought, I don't know where that blue background is possibly coming from. I can try to give you the whole css but there's a lot in here.

Comment: Have you had a look with the developer tools? Looks like an issue with the span, if you remove the pseudoelement is it showing blue?